# Including jQuery in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm doing a small project where I need to do some dynamic generation of some HTML on a form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

Since I'm a rookie at Dynamics CRM 2011 (and indeed all the prior versions), I need a bit of help doing this quite basic thing.

I would like to include the jQuery library for a specific form (or if you can suggest how I add it for all pages in Dynamics CRM I would also like to know that), so that I can setup another WebResource which will contain code to run the jQuery I need to be run.

**So the question is simple:**

How do I add jQuery to be included on all pages or a single form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Look very much forward to your help :-)

Thanks in advance!